# Mongoose Embedded Document Pre Save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models, one of them is `User` and the other one is `Reservation`. I want to embed a User object to every Reservation. User is already created and stored in Users collection. When I try to create a new Reservation object, my User object goes through pre save method and eventually fails because there is unique username field. Is there a way to bypass that pre save method when embedding objects to another collection or is my approach it completely wrong? My code for Reservation schema. Thanks!

```
import User from './../users/users.model';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export default new Schema({
  user: {
    type: User
  }
});
```

Edit: When I define the Schema explicitly it bypasses the pre save method (which makes sense), but if I want to change the Schema, I need to change it in two different places.

Comment: The unique constraint should resolve to a mongo unique constraint, and shouldn't apply to sub documents (unless specified, and even then I'm not sure how that would work).  Is it possible you want to embed the User schema and not the User model, and possibly not include the unique constraint when defining the Reservation schema.

Comment: Which version of mongoose you're using? Have you checked this open issue although it is old: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2645 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this process.

Instead of refer full **collection** you should refer a specific **user** for a **Reservation** document .When you will save or create new `Reservation` information you should pass user `id` to store as `ObjectId` and refer that `id` to user model to refer `user` model use `ref` keyword. so you can populate easily **user** from **Reservation** model.

like:

```
user:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
```

instead of

```
user: {
    type: User
  }
```

**Or** if you want to embedded **user schema** in  **reservation schema** then can use like

```
user: {
        type: [User]
      }
```

Comment: I know that I can refer the object but I want to embed it. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Instead of refer full collection you should refer a specific user for a Reservation document by passing id

Comment: Having User in an Array has no effect. It still goes through validation